# What is the correct way to handle scroll animations on Safari

Tags: scroll, safari

What is the correct way to handle scroll-event related animations in safari (like scroll syncing between two elements)?

The solution I use today works seamlessly on Chrome and Firefox, but is really laggy/jumpy in Safari.

To summarize the code, it is something like:

```
element.addEventListener("scroll", () => {   
    window.requestAnimationFrame(){  
          otherElementWithScroll.scrollTop = element.scrollTop  
          otherElementWithHorizontalScroll.scrollLeft = element.scrollLeft  
    }   
})

otherElementWithScroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {   
    window.requestAnimationFrame(){  
          element.scrollTop = otherElementWithScroll.scrollTop  
    }   
})  

otherElementWithHorizontalScroll.addEventListener("scroll", () => {   
    window.requestAnimationFrame(){  
          element.scrollLeft = otherElementWithHorizontalScroll.scrollLeft  
    }   
})
```